# End Of Line C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, sockets

I'm doing a python program who reads a C++ packet received by socket.
I unpack it and it goes well until it arrives to the finish, I suppose that python don't understand C++ EOL character, "\0" if I'm not wrong.

So I think I should search in the string the "\0" character and replace with python EOL, but I don't know which character it is! I searched but didn't find, thought it's "\000", but doesn't work, this is what I'm trying:

```
def decode(s):
    return s\
        .replace('\0','\000')\

data,adr = clientSkt.recvfrom(56)
r1,r2,r3 = unpack('B5s50s',data) #unsigned char, string[5], string[50]
r3 = decode(r3)
```

FOUND IT:
What I've done is to search the scape char \0, and then cut the string which is 50 chars long between the index of the scape char, see:

```
def decode(s):
i = 0
while (s[i] != "\0"):
    i+=1
s = s[:-(50-i)]
print "Scape char is in " ,i
return s

data,adreca = skt1.recvfrom(56)
r1,r2,r3 = unpack('B5s50s',data)
print "r1=" ,r1
print "r2=" ,r2
print "r3=" ,r3
r3 = decode(r3)
print "r3=" ,r3
```

Comment: `\0` is not end of line, its `null`

Comment: can you print the contents of the binary data and post it? Add this to your code... `import binascii; print binascii.hexlify(data)` and post the results.  Thanks!

Comment: r1= 2
r2= 0000
r3= Usuari o extensio incorrectes�L]��&{V��Q]�
Binari data:  557375617269206f20657874656e73696f20696e636f7272656374657300b44c5db7a8267b0800000000000956b7ea515db7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're reading a fixed length string from a packet, the string ends with a null character if it doesn't fill the buffer, and there might be garbage after the string. You need to detect the null character and erase it and all the characters after it.

```
def trim_zeros(s):
    i = s.find('\x00')
    if i < 0:
        return s
    return s[0:i]
```

Comment: yes men! just discovered that and now it's working, but thanks too! ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Python you do not have a `"\0"` character terminating the string.

Try:

```
def decode(s):
    return s[:-1] if s[-1] == "\0" else s
```

Comment: r1= 2
    r2= 0000
    r3= Usuari o extensio incorrectes�L]��&{V��Q]�
    Decoded r3= Usuari o extensio incorrectes�L]��&{V��Q]�

Still getting same error!

Comment: And how python know that a string it's temrminated? I know its not \0 character, but i has to have one, no?

Comment: The (C-based) implementation may use null-terminated strings internally, but this detail is not exposed to the Python interface.